# Convert from digit number to hex string with zero leading digit

Tags: python, syntax, converters, built-in

Is there a built-in Python function that convert from digit number to hex string with zero leading digit?

I wrote her:

```
def convert_to_hex_string(number):
    number = format(number, 'x')
    if len(number) == 1:
        number = '0' + number
    return number

>>> convert_to_hex_string(7)
'07'
>>> convert_to_hex_string(10)
'0a'
>>> convert_to_hex_string(11)
'0b'
>>> convert_to_hex_string(666)
'29a'
```

but I was wondering could already have a built-in in Python (analogue `.toString("X2")` in C#)

Comment: Why tagged c#??

Comment: If you wouldn't do it directly on format() using '02x' then use len(number)%2 == 1, not len(number) == 1.

Comment: try '{0:02x}'.format( number )

Comment: @lmad I search for analogue function in C# - .toString("X2")

Comment: See the duplicate target for multiple methods, but as you've already used `format`, just `format(number, '02x')` will do.

Comment: I take my word back. format with 02x doesn't work at all. (and this question is not a duplicate of the mentioned post). Anyway, just use len(number)%2 == 1. It works in C# with ToString("X2") but not in python.

Comment: @cetin-basoz can you explain in what case, 02x not work?

Comment: If someone didn't lock replies to this question I had the explanation with explicit code already :( Anyway, with format(666, '02x') or print('{0:02x}', format(666)) you just get 29a, not 029a.